# Plugin project :razorpay_flutter not found. Please update settings.gradle

Tags: flutter

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                   ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.2.4/lib/razorpay_flutter.dart:1:8:    Error: Not found: 'dart:js' import 'dart:js';

```
  ^                                                                                                            ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.2.4/lib/razorpay_flutter.dart:91:29:    Error: The getter 'context' isn't defined for the class 'Razorpay'.
```

- 'Razorpay' is from 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart'    ('../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.2.4/lib/razorpay_flutter.dart').    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or    defining a getter or field named 'context'.              _eventEmitter.on(event, context, cb);
  ^^^^^^^                                                                                 Unhandled exception:                                                     FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ajs;    message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)    #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
  #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:657:37)                                                            #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:825:21)                                                      
  #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:572:15)                    
  #4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)
  #5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:182:27)                                                   #6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:9:30)
  #7      _startIsolate. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
  #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

  ```
                                                                                                                                          FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                                 * Where:                                                                                                            Script    '/home/sranjan/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'    line: 904                    
                                                                                                                  * What went wrong:                                                                                                  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
  ```

> Process 'command '/home/sranjan/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1                                                                                                                                 * Try:                                                                                                              Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info    or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full    insights.                                                                                                                    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                                                                                                                                                                                         BUILD FAILED in 3m 58s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done
> 241.1s (!) Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was facing this issue just replace your razorpay plugin in pubspec.yaml file with

```
razorpay_flutter: 1.2.3
```